# Get checked row elements in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have created a grid using jqgrid plugin, which is working almost fine.

```
$("#tblPreviousScanProj").jqGrid({ //set your grid id
    data: data, //insert data from the data object we created above
    datatype: 'local',
    width: 1025, //specify width; optional
    colNames:['Select','Repository/Project Path','Protex Project Name'], //define column names
    colModel:[
        {name:'Pname', index:'Select', editable: true, editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, align:'center', edittype: 'checkbox', formatter: "checkbox", width:15, formatoptions: {disabled: false}},
        {name:'Pname', index:"Repository/Project Path",width:100, shrinkToFit:true},
        {name:'ProtexName', index:"Protex Project Name", width:100, shrinkToFit:true}
    ], //define column models
    sortname: 'Repository/Project Path', //the column according to which data is to be sorted; optional
    viewrecords: true, //if true, displays the total number of records, etc. as: "View X to Y out of Z” optional
    sortorder: "asc", //sort order; optional
    caption:'<h3>Project(s) Previously Scanned</h3>', //title of grid
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum: 100,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true
});
```

Now i want to get the cell values for all checked rows. Tried the below method, but its not working for me. the alert box is showing nothing.

```
var selRowId = $('#tblPreviousScanProj').jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
alert(selRowId.join(","));
```

Comment: There's no function `joins`, it's just `join`.

Comment: @Barmar : Apologies for the Typo. I tried with join() only, but still no luck.

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(selRowId)`?

Comment: You don't have the `multiselect` option in your grid.

Comment: Your code is buggy. If you use `datatype: 'local'` then `index` must be the same as `name` in `colModel`. It's better just remove all `index` properties. The next error: you have **two** columns with **the same** `name:'Pname'` value. Moreover it's unclear *where* you use `selRowId.join(",")`. Is some row already selected? You should post more full code. I recommend you to debug the code (using developer tools of Internet Explorer or Google Chrome - press F12 to start it) before posting the question.

Comment: `$("#tblPreviousScanProj").jqGrid ("getGridParam", "selrow")` get id of selected row if you don't use `multiselect: true` option.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get all selected rows is to use the [`multiselect`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) option. Then you can use [`jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selarrrow')`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) to get the row ID's.

From the documentation:

> **selarrrow**
>
> array
>
> This options is readonly. Gives the currently selected rows when multiselect is set to true. This is a one-dimensional array and the values in the array correspond to the selected id's in the grid.

From there you can loop over the ID's to get row data, perhaps using [`getRowData`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods).